# BaseGameUtils\bin missing when implementing Google Play Game Services leaderboard

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, bin

I am trying to implement the `Google Play Game Services` leaderboard found [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init).  I imported the library `BaseGameUtils`, made it a library and added it to my main project.  But there is a little red X and a red ! on my projects (see below picture).

[image]

Also, it says that the `C:\Users\lyonsmg\Downloads\android-samples-master\BaseGameUtils\bin` is missing in my Android Dependencies for my main project, `BibleTriviaLite` (see below picture).

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  I was able to import the `google-play-services_lib` correctly but not the `BaseGameUtils`.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Check the project properties for BaseGameUtils. Go to Project Properties | Android and check that it's targeting a valid Android target (there should be exactly one target checked) that's API level >= 8.
2. Check that BaseGameUtils is referencing google-play-services_lib as a dependency. To do this, go to Project Properties | Android and look at the References section. If there is nothing there, add a reference to google-play-services_lib.
3. Check that both google-play-services_lib and BaseGameUtils are set up as library projects. Go to Project Settings | Android and verify that both have the "Is Library" checkbox checked.
4. Clean and rebuild everything.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and I think it was because you haven't added the google-play-service.jar to the BaseGameUtils project. I did this in eclipse by finding an error in the project, I used GamesClient in BaseGameActivity.java on the method getGamesClient() and hovered my mouse over GamesClient until the dropdown box appeared. I then clicked fix project setup. On the popup window click add google-play-service.jar (the 2nd one in the list) then click ok. This fixed the error for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me. Even I have referred `google-play-services_lib` as a dependency for `BaseGameUtils` I still had errors until I explicitly copy  `google-play-service.jar` in BaseUtils\...\libs

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the google doc, imho. If i import a project , set it as lib, and add it as a reference to my code/project I would have never thought I would have to add it to compile path manually as well ( of course i want to compile it , no?) . Everything was set like above, I retested three times. Didn't work. BaseGameUtils would'n find the reference of com.google...gsm. Only if I **manually add** google play service library project to **java build path** under projects for the project BaseGameUtils it would a compile. (Eclipse 4.3.0)

from the short instructions by Google's github [doc](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples#if-youre-using-eclipse)

If you're using Eclipse...

1. Start Eclipse
2. Import the desired sample (Project | Import | Android | Existing Android Source)
3. Import the Google Play Services library project (available for download through the SDK manager). Make sure that the sample is REFERENCING the library project (Project Properties | Android | References)
4. Import libraries/BaseGameUtils AS A LIBRARY Make sure that the sample is REFERENCING the library project (Project Properties | Android | References)
5. Now jump to the Modify IDs, compile and run section and continue to follow the instructions there.